# Spring - use bean inside an ApplicationEventListener

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, event-listener

I have a bean which I want to "start" only after the context is up (meaning all beans have been created).

I can subscribe to the event of the "application context is up" as follows:

```
@EventListener
public void handleApplicationEvents(ApplicationReadyEvent applicationReadyEvent) {
    log.info("ApplicationReady Event received.");
    // Here I want to start an already created bean.
}
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Can you define bean as Lazy?

Comment: I can, but no one is calling this bean. The only call it will ever get is the one I want to do in the eventlistener (calling it's start() method).
It is important the the start() method will be executed after all beans have been created.

Comment: Use the `Lifecycle` or `SmartLifeCycle` interface for that. Also starting and creating beans are different things. SO you can still create the bean but it doesn't do anything before `start` is called. Why is the ordering so important? Another solution is to let the bean implement `SmartInitializingSingleton`.